# Using Redis for authentication tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am making a mobile app for a site with users, so in the app, users need to be able to sign in. To do this, I am creating a remember token to authenticate users on sign in. At first I was thinking about saving each token to the database and destroying it when the user signs out. When the user signs in, they would have the same token until they sign out. Then I saw somethings saying redis was the best way to store the tokens. My question is that if the only time a new token is created is when a user signs in and the only time it is destroyed is when a user signs out, is redis needed or is just saving it to the database ok performance wise

Answer (score 2):

Redis will enable fast access to token data as it keeps the key value pair in memory.
Also, in case you need to expire token after a particular span of time Redis will allow you to set expiration time along with key .Thus you need not perform any explicit computation to determine its expiry time in order to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

A use case of sessions using Redis is [Magento](http://magento.com/products/overview#community).

That commerce framework relies heavily on caching, storing everything in Mysql until v.1.7

From that on, they embedded a model to store sessions in Redis.

I've used Redis with success. [phpredis](http://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) is the best client for php, since it's a c extension.

I would fiddle in heroku's for verifying performance.

(Now I CAN, because of [hack](http://hacklang.org/) support there hehe =)).

My two cents.